# Regex pattern matching literal repeated \n

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, newline

Given a literal string such as:

```
Hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nWorld
```

I would like to reduce the repeated `\n`'s to a single `\n`.

I'm using PHP, and been playing around with a bunch of different regex patterns. So here's a simple example of the code:

```
$testRegex = '/(\\n){2,}/';
$test = 'Hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nWorld';
$test2 = preg_replace($testRegex ,'\n',$test); 
echo "<hr/>test regex<hr/>".$test2;
```

I'm new to PHP, not that new to regex, but it seems '\n' conforms to special rules. I'm still trying to nail those down.

**Edit:** I've placed the literal code I have in my php file here, if I do `str_replace()` I can get good things to happen, but that's not a complete solution obviously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To match a literal `\n` with regex, your string literal needs four backslashes to produce a string with two backlashes that’s interpreted by the regex engine as an escape for one backslash.

```
$testRegex = '/(\\\\n){2,}/';
$test = 'Hello\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nWorld';
$test2 = preg_replace($testRegex, '\n', $test);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to double up the escape in the regular expression?

```
$pattern = "/\\n+/"

$awesome_string = preg_replace($pattern, "\n", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

***Edit:** Just read your comment on the accepted answer. Doesn't apply, but is still useful.*

If you're intending on expanding this logic to include other forms of white-space too:

```
$output = echo preg_replace('%(\s)*%', '$1', $input);
```

Reduces all repeated white-space characters to single instances of the matched white-space character.

Answer (score -1):

it indeed conforms to special rules, and you need to add the "multiline"-modifier, m. So your pattern would look like

```
$pattern = '/(\n)+/m'
```

which should provide you with the matches. See the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for all modifiers and their detailed meaning.

Since you're trying to reduce all newlines to one, the pattern above should work with the rest of your code. Good luck!

Comment: This is 100% incorrect guidance.  The `m` pattern modifier has nothing to do with newlines.  The `m` flag is absolutely useless if a pattern does not contain `^` or `$` (anchor characters).  I must DV this post because it will misinform/confuse researchers.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/35771159/2943403

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression:

/[\n]*/