# m regex pattern modifiers

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
$subject = "SIverygood \n SIverygood\n";
$pattern = '/^SI/m';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches2,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
var_dump($matches2);
```

I am unable to understand **m** and **s** modifier. I want to get SI at the beginning of every newline. I do it for practise purpose to understand the m and s modifier.
The above example just return first **SI**. But i want both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `m` is a multi-line modifier which will makes the start anchor matches the start of each line instead of whole of your string. And in your string at the start of first line you have `SI` and it returns it but in second line the start of the line is a **space** not `SI`.

If you want to ignore the whitespaces at the leading of your line you can use following regex:

```
$pattern = '/^\s*(SI)/m';
```

And get the result of first matched group. Read more about modifiers http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: And Please explain what is the use of s modifier

Comment: @Curious Check out the attached link.